# Is there a function to graph the sampling distribution of a population sample?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, inference

I am currently taking a statistics course. There we drew a sampling distribution for a population sample. Is there any way to do it in R?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stat_function` in `ggplot`, which allows to visualize functions like `dnorm` which is a function to generate a normal distribution. Description for `stat_function`:

> Computes and draws a function as a continuous curve. This makes it
> easy to superimpose a function on top of an existing plot. The
> function is called with a grid of evenly spaced values along the x
> axis, and the results are drawn (by default) with a line.

You can pass the `dnorm` function to `fun` argument. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(-3,3))
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, geom = "area")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basic `hist()` function:

`Dist <- hist(YourData,breaks=10)`

`YourData` must be a vector of values, `breaks` indicates the number of cells for the histogram. You can check for other arguments using:

`?hist()`